# TabControl Add is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a C# Windows Forms app.

I have a TabControl on it, and depending on user settings, will dynamically use TabControl.Controls.Add to add a specific set of TabPages to the tabs.  The TabPages aren't special, they just have buttons and text.

Doing this dynamically, even for small amount of tabs, is slow as hell.  Every "Add" call, or using "AddRange" to add a bunch at once results in a half second or so of waiting.

SuspendLayout has no effect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have done this type of thing many times and never hit a performance issue.  Can you isolate this behavior to a small code sample and post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't the add control, it was one that one of my control has a PropertyGrid on it, and the Form_Load sets the SelectedObject, which is the slow operation.

PropertyGrid being slow is a different question!

Answer (score 0):

Try tabcontrol.Enabled = False while you add, then True when done.